# How to copy SQL Server log shipping files to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping, amazon-ec2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and would like to log ship from my local data center SQL Server instance to a log shipping target SQL Server running in AWS EC2.

What is the best way to copy the log ship files from the local SQL Server to the remote EC2 instance?

I have seen plenty of 'how to copy a file to EC2' solutions, but am wondering what is the best method for **continuous unattended file copying** (such as SQL Server T-Log files every 15 minutes).